# Using Sublime Text 3 for R - options toolbar missing on graph displays

Tags: linux, sublime-text-3, r

I've recently started using Sublime Text for R coding (on ElementaryOS Loki). Everything's running more or less smoothly, the only problem for now is that I'm missing the toolbar in the graphics device, which means that I can't export the plots or do anything with them.

The graphics device should be as shown here.

[image]